# Magento 1.9.0.1- Sign up form not working

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi guys I would really appreciate your response on this question or point me to a solution if there exist one already.

I have a sign up form on my magento site that i need customers to use but apparently the form isn't getting submitted to the database.

after clicking the submit button i get redirected to the very same page and no user accounts are created. On the other hand the registration form works fine during checkout process and user accounts get created successfully.

thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you have form_key present on your form?

Comment: as far as i can trace from my magento files in the server,  the below code is what i have  from the login.phtml from /app/design/frontend/neoshop/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml directory     <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl()?>" method="post" id="login-form">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey');?>............

Comment: is there a register.phtml in the same folder? does that have form_key also?

Comment: no. the only file i have is the directory is login.phtml form

Comment: can you update your Q with the contents of login.phtml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that you already inserted the form-key, but I had the same problem and I discovered that I was using the form-key in the wrong way/place.

1 -> Make sure that you use this code to insert the form-key:-

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

2 -> The code should be right after the line:-

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
```

3 -> Make the changes in the right files in your Theme:-

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
```

Comment: thanks guys for the support, solution by @xMageStore sorted me out. Cheers